# How to have dots as horizontal separator with inline text like in this screenshot?

Tags: css, frontend

I was surfing at [this iA Blog post](http://informationarchitects.net/blog/responsive-typography-the-basics/) the other day and tried to figure out **how did they do the dots as separator around the date**.

I looked at CSS and figured out it is possible only with their own special font. Is there a way to do that without using their font? What would be some hacks without using images to do the same thing?

Screenshot below:

---

[image: iA blog]

Comment: I don’t see any such dotted line on the actual page (tested on Firefox, Chrome, IE on Win 7).

Comment: As Korpela, I am also unable to see the dotted line. Besides, the CSS for the section-separator class has a before property (not pseudo element) that I would say is not correct

Comment: Why is it not correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a negative (relative em) margin to place the header over the dotted top-border of the containing block. This should keep the code save when the font-size changes. See [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/puyqJ) for an example.

Comment: This one looks good. But I can't get it working on `<time>` element. It works only on `h1`, `h2` etc.

Comment: I solved it by adding `display: table` to the element inside the div.block.

Comment: What if there is a background pattern used on `<body>`? How does one handle that?

Comment: For this solution, you need the white background to hide the dots behind the header element. If you have a background image or pattern, you might want to try the solution of xpy (which is very nice, BTW).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question once and I came up with this:

```
.lined{ display:table-row; width:auto; white-space:nowrap; position:relative; }
.lined:before,.lined:after {content:''; 
display:table-cell; 
width:50%;
position:relative;
height:20px;
background: url(http://www.xpy.gr/css/img/text-deco.png) 7px no-repeat;
}
```

I uses pseudo elements and some table-like functionality. It has some limitations but it will always stretch up to full width. All you have to do is change the `background` and add the class to the element of you choice.

DEMO: http://dabblet.com/gist/2172806

Comment: +1, *Very* nice! For small and tidy graphics (like the dots in the original example) I'd embed them with base64 directly into the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use, say, a `div` with a dotted border on the top, like in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pYMh/1/).

Basically you can put the text over the border (i.e. with absolute positioning) and apply a white background to it.

```
<div>
    <p>I. JUNE 2012</p>
</div>


div {
  border-top: 2px dotted #eee;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;        
}

p {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: It's `1 June 2012` by the way, rendered in small caps and by a font that has non-lining numerals.

Comment: I prefer to center using this transform trick:

    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

Answer (score 1):

Create an element with a dotted border, and in it center an element with a white background and a position that overflows the parent's height.

A crude example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="title_container">
    <div class="title">I. June 2012</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.title_container {position:relative;height:20px;border-bottom:1px dotted #000;}

.title_container .title {display:table;position:relative;top:10px;left:0;right:0;margin:0 auto;padding:0 10px;background:#FFF;}
```

See **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/soboaz/MrtXj/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3wtNT/). But it's probably not very robust against font and size changes.

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div class='dotted'>
        <span>2013-03-10</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 30em;
}

.dotted {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 1em;
    border-top: 1px dotted #888;
    overflow-y: visible;
}

.dotted span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -0.75em;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 1ex;
}
```